# Sybase, data type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sybase, sqldatatypes

I have 2 queries:

(1)

```
declare @m varchar  
set @m='10'  
select * from test where month=@m
```

(2)

```
declare @m varchar(2)  
set @m='10'  
select * from test where month=@m
```

Number of rows in result is different. In 2 variant more than in first. What is the reason could be?

Comment: You can debug by trying to select what you have set for `@m` so after `set` try `select @m`. SO that you can see what is stored in the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because when you don't specify how many bytes the `varchar` variable can hold, the engines uses the [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) with is `1`:

> When n isn't specified in a data definition or variable declaration
>   statement, the default length is 1. If n isn't specified when using
>   the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30.

So, in the first case you have:

```
select * from test where month=1
```

and in the second:

```
select * from test where month=10
```

Comment: Thanks, It's helped me.